# How to you fetch all transactions ERC-20/ERC-721(swap, mint, burn) of a wallet?

Tags: etherscan, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs, external-api, api

I'm looking for an API that will give me exactly  All transactions for a wallet, clearly broken down and labelled as Nft transfers, erc20 transfers, Nft purchases, token swaps etc. I've seen Moralis but it's not very comprehensive.